# How can I design a hierarchical search?

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I want to design a search engine for my website so I am giving keyword to search a pdf file for that how can I design a hierarchical search ?

Comment: very easy just store the location of the file in your database system

Comment: FileTable
---------------------------------------------
id | filepath | keywords | fileType

Answer (score 0):

You want to store the name of the pdf file in the database and then get the name of and create url with your folder path of pdf file
In this way you get file name from database and get file from your folder.
Thanks

Comment: Please like my answer and add me on skype: harryr891. In future you have any query let me know. I have 4+ years exp in wordpress, magento , core php,laravel,shopify, mobile api's

Comment: @HaninderSingh Easy on the self-promotion. It's generally best to advertise that in your profile if you need to, not spike in comments like this. If you're looking to do quick mentoring, set up a [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is) or [CodeMentor](http://codementor.io) link on your profile page.